# Python string editing in Snakemake

Tags: python, snakemake

I'm running a custom perl script using Snakemake. I use this rule:

```
rule complexity_20mer_counter:
    input:
       os.path.join(fastq_trimmed_dir, '{sample}_{read}' + fastq_extension.split('.')[0] + '_val_' + '{read}'.strip('R') + '.fq.gz')
    output:
        os.path.join(custom_qc_dir, '{sample}_{read}_20mer_counter.txt')
    shell:
        '''
        #!/bin/bash
        perl scripts/20mer_counter.pl {input} > {output}
        '''
```

It fails (I'll get to why later) with this error:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingInputException in line 1 of /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/2019-01-24/rules/20mer_counter.smk:
Missing input files for rule complexity_20mer_counter:
fastq_trimmed/xs0067_P2018SEQE27R01_S1_R1_001_val_R1.fq.gz
```

... this is because I use the output of trim_galore, this rule looks like this:

```
rule trim_galore:
    input:
       [os.path.join(fastq_raw_dir, '{sample}_'+ read + fastq_extension)
       for read in reads]
    output:
        timmed_fastq_files = [os.path.join(fastq_trimmed_dir, '{sample}_' + read + fastq_extension.split('.')[0] + '_val_' + read.strip('R') + '.fq.gz')
        for read in reads],
        trimming_reports = [os.path.join(trim_galore_qc_dir, '{sample}_'+ read + fastq_extension + '_trimming_report.txt')
        for read in reads]
    conda:
        "../envs/fastqc.yaml"
    shell:
        '''
        #!/bin/bash
        trim_galore --fastqc --gzip -o {fastq_trimmed_dir} --paired --retain_unpaired {input}
        # Move all qc reports to the fastq_trimmed_dir
        mv {fastq_trimmed_dir}/*.zip \
           {fastq_trimmed_dir}/*.html \
           {fastq_trimmed_dir}/*.txt \
           {trim_galore_qc_dir}
        '''
```

As you can see, trim_galore not only uses my {read} parameter in the output filename but again adds it at the end, only now without the "R".

I tried solving it in my first rule by applying a python .strip('R') on my {read} wildcard, but this does not seem to work. How can I correctly get '1' and '2' from 'R1' and 'R2' (which are my {read} wildcards)?

(Extra bonus points for a nice output.trim_galore.something as input for my complexity_20mer_counter rule, which does not work because the output is a list (it needs 2 fastq files at the same time), but my complexity_20mer_counter rule *can* be run in parallel again.)

Comment: For me it's quite hard to give you a final solution, without having a look on the whole `Snakefile` or at least a runnable minimal example. I would suggest that the values for `read` are already without the `R`. Than you can easily decide when a `R` is needed in the filename and when not.

Comment: This Snakefile is quite difficult to follow, and its complexity means that subtle mistakes might easily creep in. For example, in your `trim_galore` rule you have `timmed_fastq_files` instead of `trimmed_fastq_files` as the label for your output files. I don't know if this is a problem, but little things like that can definitely mess up the whole pipeline. Also, the shebang at the beginning of each "shell" directive is unnecessary. :-)

Comment: Yes, I already caught the timmed error, it was not it. I did try putting reads to ['1', '2'] and making _R part of the string but may people use my pipelines and I want to make the default what every is used most. Doing what @finswimmer suggests will lead to a lot of code to make the "R" optional somehow. Although one could probably figure something out. I would just like to do string operations in the wildcard, like {read}.strip('R'). I'll try to look into making something minimal working but that is a lot of effort in this large pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible to apply `strip()` directly on the wildcard placeholders. Luckily it is possible to executed functions in the `input` directive.

So try changing your input of the `complexity_20mer_counter` rule to this:

```
lambda wc: os.path.join(fastq_trimmed_dir, wc.sample + '_' + wc.read + fastq_extension.split('.')[0] + '_val_' + wc.read.strip('R') + '.fq.gz')
```

The wildcard object is passed to our anonymous function. So have access to the wildcards value via `wc.sample` and `wc.read`, which are now handled as normal strings and we can apply `strip` on them.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for, it works, thank you! (I did call "wildcards", not "wc", not sure if that is supported, I call "wildcards" everywhere.